# jQuery animate after resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, centering

I'm using [jQuery Image Center plugin](http://boxlight.github.io/bl-jquery-image-center/) and trying to animate image after it is centered

here is my code, image centering works but animation doesn't

```
$('#myimage').css('opacity' , 0);
$('#myimage').centerImage(function() {
  //At this point, resize is complete, and the element is invisible
  $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 1500 );
});
```

Comment: do you get any errors on console ?

Comment: No, nothing in firebug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [plugin source](https://github.com/boxlight/bl-jquery-image-center/blob/master/js/jquery.blImageCenter.js), second argument is the callback and first one method of centering. So try

```
var $img =$('#myimage');
$img.css('opacity', 0);

$img.centerImage('inside', function () { //give inside or for no method just provide undefined or ""
      //At this point, resize is complete, and the element is invisible
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1500);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2R9Fn/)**

**[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/aTjrJ/)**

Also remember you can chain em through as in the demo.

Comment: @Darko You are welcome. If you don't mind (or did not get another better answer) please remember to mark as answer.